# Ordenar una tabla de un DataSet por una columna

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dataset

Tengo un DataSet que llamado "ds" con una tabla llamada "tabla1" que contiene 2 columnas "Descripcion" y "Argumento".Quiero ordenar ese mismo dataset para que la tabla se vea por orden ascendente segun la columna "Descripcion". Mas tarde ese dataset lo tengo que enviar a un metodo que recibira por "referencia" el DataSet ordenado.

He probado a hacer lo siguiente:

```
ds.Tables["Tabla1"].DefaultView.Sort = "Descripcion ASC"
```

Pero esto no me ordena el DataSet.

Tambien he probado con:

```
DataView dtv =  ds.Tables["Tabla1"].DefaultView;
dtv.Sort = "Descripcion ASC";
ds.Tables = dtv.ToTable;
```

pero me dice que no se puede asignar porque la propiedad DataSet.Tables es de solo lectura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que como tal no estás ordenando tú tabla, sino más bien creando una **vista ordenada de tu tabla**, para ordenar tu tabla haz lo siguiente:

```
ds.Tables["Tabla1"].DefaultView.Sort = "Descripcion";
```

Hasta aquí lo que hacemos es crear una vista de la tabla ordenada ascendentemente por el **campo Descripcion**.

Posteriormente harías esto:

```
DataTable miTabla = ds.Tables["Tabla1"].DefaultView.ToTable(true);
```

Convertimos la **vista ordenada** a un **DataTable**, y de esta forma ya tenemos la **tabla ordenada**.

Como no puedes hacer **ds.Tables["Tabla1"] = miTabla**, ya que la tabla dentro del **DataSet** es de solo lectura entonces haz lo siguiente:

```
miTabla.TableName = "TablaOrdenada";
ds.Tables.Add(miTabla);

if (ds.Tables.Contains("Tabla1"))
{
   ds.Tables.Remove("Tabla1");
}
```

Le damos un nombre al **DataTable**, añadimos dicho **DataTable** ordenado al **DataSet** y eliminamos la tabla anterior si lo deseas. También puedes dejar las dos tablas si lo deseas, la original y la ordenada (Valora tu cualquier opción).

Comment: Ok pero me interesa que el mismo DataSet contenga esa misma tabla ordenada. No hacerlo en otra tabla u otro DataSet. No se si es posible.

Comment: @Popularfan, eso no tiene problema, asigna el datatable a la tabla del dataset

Comment: @Popularfan, revisa lo nuevo que puse

Comment: no  puedo asignar el datatable a la tabla del dataset creada con la vista. Me indica que no se puede asignar a la propiedad o el indizador 'DataTableCollection.this[string]' porque es de solo lectura.

Comment: @Popularfan, Revisa de nuevo

Comment: Funciona perfecto, pero en mi caso me interesa que la nueva tabla tenga el mismo nombre así que borro antes la tabla antigua con 'Remove' para agregar la otra con el mismo nombre con 'Add'

Comment: @Popularfan, muy bien asi se hace